# How can I run an ant task as a prerequisite to <taskdef>?

Tags: java, ant, taskdef

I created my own ant task using the instructions [here](https://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-writing-tasks.html).  In my ant script, I create the `<taskdef>` like this:

```
<!-- myUploader.xml -->
<taskdef name="fileUpload" classname="com.awt.client.UploaderTask" classpath="lib/fileUploader.jar" />

<target name="setup" description="some required setup before taskdef!">
    <!-- checking for required jars, etc... -->
</target>
```

And then I can import the script that invokes this as an ant task:

```
<!-- build.xml -->
<import file="myUploader.xml" />
<fileUpload server="${server}" username="${username}" password="${password}" appname="TestApp" appversion="13" />
```

This all works fine.  Now, there is a bit of setup I would like to happen in myUploader.xml before the taskdef occurs.  `<taskdef>` does not like `if`, `unless`, or `depends`.  How can I ensure that my setup task is called before `<taskdef>` is done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to move the `taskdef` inside the `setup` target:

```
<target name="setup" description="some required setup before taskdef!">
    <!-- checking for required jars, etc... -->
    <taskdef name="fileUpload" classname="com.awt.client.UploaderTask" classpath="lib/fileUploader.jar" />
</target>
```

Then in the main buildfile, after importing `myUploader.xml`, invoke the `setup` target which is now responsible for defining your custom task.

Or you can move the part of the `setup` target to outside (becoming a top-level section):

```
<project>

     <!-- do required setup here -->
   <taskdef name="fileUpload" classname="com.awt.client.UploaderTask" classpath="lib/fileUploader.jar" />

...
```

Comment: This is my current workaround, I'm glad to see I'm on the right track.  I plan to distribute myUploader.xml with a product and I'm trying to get the setup as simple as possible (no dependencies other than the import).  I was hoping for just a single import and then we could invoke the task.  But this is my runner-up choice right now.

Comment: If the setup part is needed, why not simply remove it from the target and place it before the `taskdef`, i.e. put the setup outside any target so that it runs when import `myUploader.xml`.

Comment: I'm fairly new when it comes to ant and I didn't know I could do that.  That does exactly what I needed, thanks!  If you want to update your answer I will accept it.